# How to make Xcode 4.5 project work on previous version of Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way if I developed an iPhone app on Xcode 4.5, that it can be compiled on Xcode 4.4.1, or if developed on 4.4.1, compiled on 4.3?

---

Details: I usually like to upgrade to the latest version of Xcode, but recently headhunters introduced me to some companies, and some of them ask me to write a sample app per their specs.  They don't specify what platform they use, and the problem usually is not trivial, so the time spent can be 4, 5 hours.  So after 4, 5 hours, when I send to the company, they may spend 1 or 2 minutes and decide that "it can't compile" and toss it aside, without even contacting me that it won't compile, and without even telling me that they got the project in email already.  Maybe this is life.  And it seems a good practice to always ask the company what Xcode they will use to test the sample project.  But as of right now, I have an Xcode 4.5 project, and the interviewer told me they are using Xcode 4.4.1, and somehow, I need to convert the project back to a 4.4.1 one.

Comment: This is probably more an issue of base SDK and deployment target setting than the Xcode version *per se*.  Either way, agree best to ask what their Xcode version and deployment targets would be in advance.  The new way that the dev tools are packaged makes it easier to have multiple versions on your machine.