# Fill ImageView with a Pattern

Tags: objective-c

I`m trying to fill a ImageView with a Pattern, but its increasing size rather than filling.

Comment: How is related to the `xcode IDE`? Just because you are using `xcode` doesn't mean you should use the `xcode` tag. The `xcode` tag is reserved for issues relating the `xcode IDE` itself such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986341/ios-project-update-xcode-4-2-to-xcode-4-5 that is a real `xcode` issue.

Comment: @Popeye thanks! I did not know, I learned now so I wont do that anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a resizable tile image from a previous image by doing

```
tileImage = [originalImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
```

now, you can take this image and set it in any image view.  the image will tile in order to fill the entire image view.