# how to add QuartzCore.framework in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I create one application and I so need QuartzCore.framework for add in my project but when search in framework list not found in it.
this is my project :

please tell me how to add this framework in xcode. (my xcode is 4.5 version)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986341/ios-project-update-xcode-4-2-to-xcode-4-5/16069431#16069431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is

> You should reinstall your xcode or update your xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If you have another MAC at your end then just copy QuartzCore.framework and past into your MAC.

Comment: have you mac ? my friend can you guide me and give me this framework?

Comment: get this : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/113626588/QuartzCore.framework.zip

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? By "past" did you mean "paste"?